# Expressjs - All Routes Are 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-status-code-404, url-routing

In My Express App, for some reason, all of the routes are returning 404.

Server.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies
 */

var express = require('express')
var passport = require('passport')
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
var config = require('./config/config')[env]
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var fs = require('fs')

require('./helpers')
require('express-namespace')

mongoose.connect(config.db)

// Bootstrap models
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/app/models').forEach(function (file) {
  if (~file.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/app/models/' + file)
})

// Bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport, config)

var app = express()

// Bootstrap application settings
require('./config/express')(app, config, passport)

// Bootstrap routes
require('./config/routes')(app, passport)

// Start the app by listening on <port>
var port = config.port || process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port)
console.log('Express app started on port '+port)

// Expose app
module.exports = app
```

Routes.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var passportOptions = {
  failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password.',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}

// controllers
var home = require('home')
var functions = require('function')

/**
 * Expose
 */

module.exports = function (app, passport) {

  console.log("SR");
  app.get('/', function(req,res){
    console.log("//////");
  })
  app.get('/functions/get',functions.get)
  app.post('/functions/submit',functions.sub)
  app.get('/login',passport.authenticate('google',{
    "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "hd":"kinokiapp.com"
  }))
  app.get('/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect:"/" }),function(req,res){
    res.end("auth")
  })

console.log("ER");
}
```

Home.js

```
/*!
 * Module dependencies.
 */

console.log("HIH");

exports.index = function (req, res) {
  res.render('home', {
    title: 'Node Express Mongoose Boilerplate'
  })
}
```

function.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var KIFunction = mongoose.model("KIFunction")

exports.get = function(req, res) {
    res.type('text/kinoki-function')
    res.status(200);
    var exclude
    try {
        exclude = JSON.parse(req.query.n)
    } catch (e) {
        exclude = []
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < exclude.length; i++) {
        if (typeof exclude[i] != 'string') {
            continue;
        }
        exclude[i] = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(exclude[i])
    }
    KIFunction.random({
        "_id":{
            "$nin":exclude
        },
        approved1:true,
        approved2:true,
    }).limit(10).exec(function(err,functions){
        if (err || functions.length == 0) {return res.end("false")}
        var out = ''
        functions.forEach(function(f){
            out += "{0}#{1}#{2}#{3}|".format(f.steps, f.string, f.difficulty, f._id)
        })

        res.end(out.substring(0, out.length - 1),"utf8")
    })
}


exports.sub = function(req,res){
    var fstr = req.body.str
    if (!(req.body.hasOwnProperty("str")) || !(fstr.match(KIFunction.functionRegex()))) {
        res.status(400)
        res.end("false")
        return
    }

    new KIFunction({
        string:fstr
    }).save(function(err){
        if(err) {
            res.status(200)
            return res.end("false")
        }
        res.status(200)
        res.end("true")
    })
}
```

the output is:

> 23 Aug 08:21:16 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js` HIH SR ER
>   Express app started on port 3000 
>   GET / 404 571ms - 863b

config/config.js

```
/*!
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var path = require('path')
var rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname + '../..')

/**
 * Expose config
 */

module.exports = {
  development: {
    root: rootPath,
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/kinoki_dev',
    rootURL:"http://localhost/",
    logger: 'dev'
  },
  test: {
    root: rootPath,
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/kinoki_test',
    rootURL:"http://localhost/",
    port: 9273,
    logger: false
  },
  ci: {
    root: rootPath,
    db: ("mongodb://" + process.env.WERCKER_MONGODB_HOST + ":" + process.env.WERCKER_MONGODB_PORT + "/kinoki_ci"),
    port: 2547,
    rootURL:"http://localhost/",
    logger: false
  },
  production: {
    root: rootPath,
    dbpass:"xyz",
    db: 'mongodb://user:pass@mymongoserver.com:39768/kinoki',
    rootURL:"http://kinokiapp.com/",
    logger: 'dev'
  }
}
```

config/express.js

```
/*!
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express)
var helpers = require('view-helpers')
var pkg = require('../package')
var flash = require('connect-flash')
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
var config = require("./config")[env]

/*!
 * Expose
 */

module.exports = function (app, config, passport) {
  // Add basic auth for staging
  if (env === 'staging') {
    app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass){
      return 'username' == user & 'password' == pass
    }))

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      if (req.remoteUser && req.user && !req.user._id) {
        delete req.user
      }
      next()
    })
  }

  app.set('showStackError', true)

  // use express favicon
  app.use(express.favicon(config.root + '/public/favicon.ico'))

  app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'))
  if(config.logger){
    app.use(express.logger(config.logger))
  }

  // views config
  app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views')
  app.set('view engine', 'jade')

  app.configure(function () {
    // bodyParser should be above methodOverride
    app.use(express.bodyParser())
    app.use(express.methodOverride())

    // cookieParser should be above session
    app.use(express.cookieParser())
    app.use(express.session({
      secret: pkg.name,
      store: new mongoStore({
        url: config.db,
        collection : 'sessions'
      })
    }))

    // Passport session
    app.use(passport.initialize())
    app.use(passport.session())

    // Flash messages
    app.use(flash())

    // expose pkg and node env to views
    app.locals({
      pkg:pkg,
      env:env
    })

    // View helpers
    app.use(helpers(pkg.name))

    // routes should be at the last
    app.use(app.router)

    // custom error handler
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
      if (err.message
        && (~err.message.indexOf('not found')
        || (~err.message.indexOf('Cast to ObjectId failed')))) {
        return next()
      }

      console.error(err.stack)
      res.status(500).render('500')
    })

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.status(404).render('404', { url: req.originalUrl })
    })
  })

  // development specific stuff
  app.configure('development', function () {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
  })

  // staging specific stuff
  app.configure('staging', function () {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
  })
}
```

config/passport.js

```
/*!
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy
var User = mongoose.model('User')
var config = require('./config')[process.env.NODE_ENV]

/**
 * Expose
 */

module.exports = function(passport, config) {
  // serialize sessions
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({
      _id: id
    }, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user)
    })
  })

  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    callbackURL: config.rootURL + 'google/callback'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({
        id: profile.id
      }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err)
        }
        if (!user) {
          user = new User({
            id: profile.id,
            profile: profile,
            accessToken:accessToken,
            refreshToken:refreshToken
          })
          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              return done(err)
            }
            done(null, user)
          })
        } else {
          done(null,user)
        }       
      })
  }
))

  passport.reqAuth = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
      return next()
    else
      res.redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

config/routes.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var passportOptions = {
  failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password.',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}

// controllers
var home = require('home')
var functions = require('function')

/**
 * Expose
 */

module.exports = function (app, passport) {

  console.log("SR");
  app.get('/', function(req,res){
    console.log("//////");
  })
  app.get('/functions/get',functions.get)
  app.post('/functions/submit',functions.sub)
  // app.get('/login',passport.authenticate('google',{
  //    "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
  //    "hd":"kinokiapp.com"
  // }))
  // app.get('/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect:"/" }),function(req,res){
  //    res.end("auth")
  // })

console.log("ER");
}
```

Does Anyone Know why all the routes are returning 404 (all of them are 404, i just don't have the logs).

Please let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Express 404's if a request gets to the end of the middleware chain without anything sending a response. So a common reason for this is a missing `app.use(app.router)`.

In your case `passport.deserializeUser(id, fn)` throws an error within `passport.session()`. Express passes the request directly to your custom error handler, bypassing `app.router`. Since the error is not 'not found' it renders `404`.

I would probably just return a user of `null` in the event that `User.findOne(...` doesn't find a user. You will need to make sure any templates that are shown to both logged-in and non-logged-in users handles both cases.

Also I use this often, it might come in handy:

```
function restrictToLoggedIn(req, res, next){
  if(req.user && req.user !== null){ 
    return next() 
  } else {
    res.send(401, 'Must be logged in');
  };
};

app.get('/'
, restrictToLoggedIn
, function(req, res, next){
// req.user is guranteed to be populated
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  res.render('home');
});
```

---

*edit: leaving troubleshooting for posterity...*

If `app.use(app.router)` already exists in your `./config/express`, check the previous middlewares. You can set a single catchall route at the top of your routes.js to make sure that anything that hits the router sends 200: `app.all('*', function(req,res){ res.send(200, req.originalUrl) });`

Finally, confirm that `require('function')` is loading properly. I always use `require('./function.js')`.

You can comment out your `app.use(passport...` middleware functions to test whether that's at fault.

If none of this helps please post your `config/*` javascript files.

Comment: sorry, that did not work, great solution though. I posted the code in config/*.

Comment: my next step would be to define a custom middleware function like `var testResponse = function(req,res){ res.send(200, req.originalUrl) };` and then place `app.use(testResponse)` at the top of your middleware chain. Continue moving it down the chain until the response 404's to identify the problem middleware

Comment: Oh I just noticed that at least `/` does not send a response, which would make it 404. `routes.get` and `routes.sub` appear to send responses though.

Comment: It looks like any request that fails to match a route should pass through to your custom error handler. When you access pages, does the page render your `404` and `500` templates as expected? Or does it send just the 404 code?

Comment: I figured it out its passport.session, i cant figure out why, does that help?

Comment: It Worked! whould you please update your answer or submit a new one so I can accept it.

Comment: Thank a lot! I caught same issue. After your eхplanation I found and fix the problem in deserializUser